# Regex expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to search "$_POST['something']" in a String by regex.
Tried it by textpad with following regex expression. `".*$_POST\['[a-zA-z0-9]*'\].*"`

When same is used in java it is now working. ?

Comment: You can test Java regex online at numerous sites, including http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the starting and trailing `.*`, but you do need to escape the `$` as it has the special meaning of the zero-width end of the string.

```
\\$_POST\\['[a-zA-Z0-9]*'\\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
"\\$_POST\\['([a-zA-Z0-9]*)'\\]"
```

Symbols like `$`have particular meanings in regex. Therefore, you need to prefix them with `\`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex pattern given as a String with the [matches(...) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) of the [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). It returns a `boolean`.

```
String a = "Hello, world! $_POST['something'] Test!";
String b = "Hello, world! $_POST['special!!!char'] Test!";
String c = "Hey there $_GET['something'] foo bar";

String pattern = ".*\\$_POST\\['[A-Za-z0-9]+'\\].*";

System.out.println ("a matches? " + Boolean.toString(a.matches(pattern)));
System.out.println ("b matches? " + Boolean.toString(b.matches(pattern)));
System.out.println ("c matches? " + Boolean.toString(c.matches(pattern)));
```

You can also use a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a Matcher object to reuse the pattern for multiple uses:

```
String[] array = {
    "Hello, world! $_POST['something'] Test!",
    "Hello, world! $_POST['special!!!char'] Test!",
    "Hey there $_GET['something'] foo bar"
};

String strPattern = ".*\\$_POST\\['[A-Za-z0-9]+'\\].*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(strPattern);

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(array[i]);
    System.out.println("Expression:  " + array[i]);
    System.out.println("-> Matches?  " + Boolean.toString(m.matches()));
    System.out.println("");
}
```

outputs:

```
Expression:  Hello, world! $_POST['something'] Test!
-> Matches?  true

Expression:  Hello, world! $_POST['special!!!char'] Test!
-> Matches?  false

Expression:  Hey there $_GET['something'] foo bar
-> Matches?  false
```